# creating a dll file in code::blocks and using it in powerpoint 2007

Tags: c++, dll, powerpoint, codeblocks, declare

I have tired to create  a dll file in code blocks and then use it in my powerpoint presentation. In the dll file as I have mentioned below the argument of  the function contains (**LPCSTR**)

```
 void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext)
{
MessageBoxA(0, sometext, "  DLL Message  ", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

In my powerpoint file I have

```
Declare Function DLL_EXPORT _
Lib "myfile.dll" _
Alias "SomeFunction" (???)
```

and when I run the file I get
[image]
Because I do not know how to define the argument of my function in the powerpoint. I mean   this part of the code:

```
 Alias "SomeFunction" (???)
```

Comment: `Declare Function SomeFunction Lib "myfile.dll" Alias "SomeFunction" (ByVal sometext As String)`. Also make sure to have your native `SomeFunction` use *Pascal* calling convention. See also [Anatomy of a Declare Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa189024%28v=office.10%29.aspx).

Comment: I already used ByVal sometext As String but it did not work. But I am not sure about the calling the function. I used just for example:  
 DLL_EXPORT ("Hello World")

Comment: `DLL_EXPORT` is not a function name. It's a C++ macro to enable using the same header file for the DLL implementation and clients of that DLL. It probably expands to `extern "C"`. The calling convention should be specified as: `DLL_EXPORT void __stdcall SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext)`.

Comment: the rest of codes for dll file is :
extern "C" DLL_EXPORT BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
some codes here ...    return TRUE; 
}

Comment: Thanks @IInspectable for your help. I got some idea from the following movie [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzO9L6tlXDI]

Answer (score 0):

Your C++ code uses the wrong calling convention. It should be:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall SomeFunction(const char* sometext)
```

You can use macros like `DLL_EXPORT`, `APIENTRY`, `LPCSTR` etc. if you wish. However, at least until you know what the macros all mean, it is probably easier to be explicit, as I show above.

The correct VBA declaration for your function is:

```
Declare Sub SomeFunction Lib "myfile.dll" (ByVal sometext As String)
```

However, this alone is not enough because your function will be subject to name decoration and mangling. You can use dumpbin or Dependency Walker to view the actual name by which your function is exported. Then your VBA declaration would need to be modified like so:

```
Declare Sub SomeFunction Lib "myfile.dll" Alias "<DecoratedNameHere>" (ByVal sometext As String)
```